# IotHub event and Azure function repeating old messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have been developing an Azure function triggered by IotHub event.
However we have noticed an odd occurrence where two specific messages keep getting processed by the Azure function from the day before. Via App Insights I am able to view the message being processed... the timestamp is from the day before and the device that is sending it is currently switched off. But for the past 5 hours the same two messages keep getting processed by the azure function.

Comment: The message may not be processed successfully, so it is always in the queue. You should set a maximum number of times to remove such messages after that.

Comment: If you limited message you can find the issue quickly. You can create new consumer group and connect with "ServiceBusExplore" see all your IoThub messages. If you don't have a duplicate message in IoThub then you can check function checkpointing in Storage account.

Comment: BowmanZhu - unfortunately this is not using queues (via message routes). The function is firing based on a message event on the IotHub. Pankaj... will try this next time. The message has since stopped sending but will try this the following time